# Dropdown list values not duplicating on refresh the page after button click (post) on page load event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I refresh the page after clicking the button that added three cities on the dropdown list but after refreshing the page it fires the page load event but cities not getting duplicated on dropdown.I have enabled view state. Can someone please explain.Thanks,

```
<table style="font-family: Arial">
    <tr>
        <td colspan = "2"><b>Employee Details Form</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name: </td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name: </td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                Text="Register Employee" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

Copy and Paste the following code in the code behind file of the web form.
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadCityDropDownList();
}
public void LoadCityDropDownList()
{
    ListItem li1 = new ListItem("London");
    ddlCity.Items.Add(li1);

    ListItem li2 = new ListItem("Sydney");
    ddlCity.Items.Add(li2);

    ListItem li3 = new ListItem("Mumbai");
    ddlCity.Items.Add(li3);
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are binding the data source at runtime you will need to add a check for `Page.IsPostBack` property as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack){
         LoadCityDropDownList();
    }
}
```

This will populate your drop down list options on the first page load only.

Read more about `IsPostBack` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: okay if I click on button it will call page load() again and re enter the values into the list but if I press F5 on browser it calls page load() as well but did not add the values into the list like button click any thoughts ? Thanks